# How can I find the common items from two arrays fast?

Tags: arrays, perl, optimization

I am trying to findy the common lines among two tab separated files based one field.
One line of the first file:

```
1       52854   s64199.1        A       .       .       .       PR      GT      0/0
```

One line of the second file:

```
chr1    52854     .       C       T       215.302 .       AB=0.692308;ABP=7.18621;AC=1;AF=0.5;AN=2;AO=9;CIGAR=1X;DP=13;DPB=13;DPRA=0;EPP=3.25157;EPPR=3.0103;GTI=0;LEN=1;MEANALT=1;MQM=60;MQMR=60;NS=1;NUMALT=1;ODDS=17.5429;PAIRED=0;PAIREDR=0.25;PAO=0;PQA=0;PQR=0;PRO=0;QA=318;QR=138;RO=4;RPP=3.25157;RPPR=5.18177;RUN=1;SAF=0;SAP=22.5536;SAR=9;SRF=1;SRP=5.18177;SRR=3;TYPE=snp;technology.illumina=1;BVAR  GT:DP:RO:QR:AO:QA:GL    0/1:13:4:138:9:318:-5,0,-5
```

Based on the second field (52854) in this example I have a much.
Here is my code which finds the common ones, but my files are quite large and takes a lot of time.
Is there any way to speed up the process?
Thank you very much in advance.

```
#!/app/languages/perl/5.14.2/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $map_file = $ARGV[0];
my $vcf_file = $ARGV[1];
open my $map_info, $map_file or die "Could not open $map_file: $!";

my @map_array = ();
my @vcf_array = ();
while( my $mline = <$map_info>)  {
    chomp $mline;
    my @data1 = split('\t', $mline);
    my $pos1 = $data1[1];
    push (@map_array, $pos1);
}
open my $vcf_info, $vcf_file or die "Could not open $vcf_file: $!";
while( my $line = <$vcf_info>)  {
    if ($line !~ m/^#/) {
            push (@vcf_array, $line);
    }
}
foreach my $a (@map_array) {
    chomp $a;
foreach my $b (@vcf_array) {
            chomp $b;
            my @data = split('\t', $b);
            my $pos2 = $data[1];
            my $ref2 = $data[3];
            my $allele = $data[4];
            my $genotype = $data[9];
            if ($a == $pos2) {
               print $pos2 . "\t" . $ref2. "\t".$allele."\t".$genotype. "\n";     
            #print "$b\n";
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of loading the data into multiple arrays, I'd use a single hash where the keys are the values of the second field.  Then as you loop over the second file, extract the desired fields and do a simple hash lookup on the key.  If it exists, output the data.  Using this approach will use less memory and doesn't need the nested foreach loops.

Comment: Your nested foreach loops is the main cause of the inefficiency because it is repeatedly looping over the complete set of data from the second file (once for every line in the first file).  Using the hash approach I suggested only loops over the second file once.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. What do you mean " do a simple hash lookup on the key"?

Comment: Are you sure your files are tab-separated? There are no tabs in the data that you've posted. And is `52854 C T 0/1:13:4:138:9:318:-5,0,-5` the output that you expect from that vcf file?

Comment: The output that I'm expected is like that: 
`1413129 G       T       1/1:19:0:0:19:684:-5,-5,0`
I believe that it is tab separated. there are four fields. The last one is a little bit strange I know, but its one field.

Answer (score 1):

Below please find minimal modification of your script for hash based searches

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $map_file = $ARGV[0];
my $vcf_file = $ARGV[1];

my %vcf_hash;
open( my $vcf_info, $vcf_file) or die "Could not open $vcf_file: $!";
while( my $line = <$vcf_info>)  {
    next if $line =~ m/^#/; # Skip comment lines
    chomp $line;
    my (@data) = split(/\t/, $line);
    die unless @data >= 10; # Check number of fields in the input line
    my ($pos) = $data[1];
    # $. - line number in the file
    $vcf_hash{$pos}{$.} = \@data;
}

open( my $map_info, $map_file) or die "Could not open $map_file: $!";
while( my $mline = <$map_info>)  {
    chomp $mline;
    my (@data) = split(/\t/, $mline);
    die unless @data >= 2; # Check number of fields in the input line
    my ($pos) = $data[1];
    if( exists $vcf_hash{$pos}) {
      my $hash_ref = $vcf_hash{$pos};
      for my $n (sort{$a<=>$b} keys %$hash_ref) {
        my $array_ref = $hash_ref->{$n};
        my $pos2     = $array_ref->[1];
        my $ref2     = $array_ref->[3];
        my $allele   = $array_ref->[4];
        my $genotype = $array_ref->[9];
        print $pos2 . "\t" . $ref2. "\t".$allele."\t".$genotype. "\n";
      }
    }
}
```

The script may be improved further to reduce memory use if you use huge data files.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working, but the output is a little bit strange. The first line that it is printed is not whole and it doesn't print only the field that are selected, it prints the whole line.

Comment: Sorry, your script was strange/unusual for me - I have not inspected it close enough to detect info you really wanted :-)

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip: The problem is with your `split` statement. You have `'\t'` in single quotes, which will try to split on the two characters backslash, `t`. You want double quotes there for a tab character. Or better, you can use slashes to reflect that it's a regular expression

Comment: @Borodin Are you SURE?  I have used splits from the script to be improved. `'\t'` splits TAB separated files on my test system (perl 5.20.2-6 on Debian/testing). Anyway I have applied your suggestion to improve portability.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip: I'm certain. `perl -E"say length '\t'"` shows 2, because there is a backslash and a `t`. And yes. I hadn't noticed the original post was wrong as well!

Comment: @Borodin `print scalar( split('\t',"a\tb b\tc"))` produces 3 on my test system.  What does it produce on your comp?

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip: Ah, you're right. Whatever string you pass it's then compiled as a regex pattern, and the two characters backslash and 't' have the same effect in that context as a single horizontal tab character. All the more reason to delimit it with slashes rather than either single or double quotes!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that should run much faster than your own

It reads the map file and stores each `pos` field in hash `%wanted`. Then it reads through the second file and checks whether the record is in the list of wanted values. If so then it splits the record and prints the fields you require

Note that I haven't been able to test this beyond making sure that it compiles

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

my ( $map_file, $vcf_file ) = @ARGV;

my %wanted;

{
    open my $map_fh, '<', $map_file;

    while ( <$map_fh> ) {
        chomp;
        my $pos = ( split /\t/, $_, 3 )[1];
        ++$wanted{$pos};
    }
}

{
    open my $vcf_fh, '<', $vcf_file;

    while ( <$vcf_fh> ) {

        next if /^#/;

        chomp;
        my $pos = ( split /\t/, $_, 3 )[1];
        next unless $wanted{$pos};

        my ( $ref, $allele, $genotype ) = ( split /\t/ )[3, 4, 9];
        print join("\t", $pos, $ref, $allele, $genotype), "\n";

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Borodin. It compiles fine. The only issue is that the $pos variable masks previous declaration. Otherwise it works fine as it seems

Comment: @Vasilis: Okay thanks, I've fixed that issue. Have you tried it with your live data? I presume that's not your downvote?

Comment: No, of course its not mine. It works perfect and very fast! Thank you very much again :)

Comment: Can I ask you and something else, cause your syntax is too advanced for me? What I have to modify if I want to print the whole line of the file?

Comment: @Vasilis: Instead of the `print join(...), "\n"` line you need just `print "$_\n"`

Answer (score 0):

There is not a need to keep your `map_file` in memory but just keys. It is good to make them keys in a hash which you use for existence checking. You don't have to keep your `vcf_file` in memory as well, but you can just make a decision to output or not.

```
#!/app/languages/perl/5.14.2/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use constant KEY => 1;
use constant FIELDS => ( 1, 3, 4, 9 );

my ( $map_file, $vcf_file ) = @ARGV;

my %map;
{
    my $fh;
    open $fh, '<', $map_file;

    while (<$fh>) {
        $map{ ( split /\t/, $_, KEY + 2 )[KEY] } = undef;
    }
}

{
    my $fh;
    open $fh, '<', $vcf_file;
    while (<$fh>) {
        next if /^#/;
        chomp;
        my @data = split /\t/;
        print join "\t", @data[FIELDS] if exists $map{ $data[KEY] };
    }
}
```